# How are HTTP responses managed by Node JS express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, url-routing

Having this simple express app example:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()


app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'))


app.get('/', function(request,response) {

    response.send("This wont matter if we got an index.hml after all")
})

app.listen(2311, function() {

    console.log("app escuchando en Maricela DDMM")
})
```

And at `/public` I got an *`index.html`*.

When I get rid of such html the string in the `send()` method will be sent, received and rendered at browser.

What does actually *happen* with the `response.send()` string talking about the HTTP response, as the HTML is which is send and so rendered at browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express goes through the chain of middleware in the order in which it was added.  You have added `express.static` as the first middleware, so it will be ran first.

In the event `express.static` cannot find a file, it calls `next()`, allowing the next bit of middleware to run.  This is your handler set up with `app.get('/' //...`, which sends the data as you have told it to.

Answer (score -1):

I think it basically sets up the header information based on the parameter in send and then send the http response